# How does it become to particular type?

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> :t 1 <> (2 :: Sum Integer)
1 <> (2 :: Sum Integer) :: Sum Integer
```

How does `1` become to `Sum Integer` type?

**Update**

I play a bit with `mappend` function and discovered:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> x = mappend 43
```

Why does mappend accept the number `43`? `43` is a `Num` type and it has no monoid instance.

Comment: Look at the type for `(<>)`.

Comment: Number literals in Haskell are overloaded using the `Num` typeclass. The `:: Sum Integer` on `2` tells Haskell that `2 :: Sum Integer` has type `Sum Integer` (which has a `Num` instance). Then, since `(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m`, Haskell knows that `1` must have the same type as `2 :: Sum Integer`.

Comment: Why does `2 :: Sum Integer` determine which type `1` has to be?

Comment: As stated by @Code-Apprentice, you should look at the type of `<>`, which is `Monoid a => a -> a -> a`. The types of both arguments must be identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly `(2 :: Sum Integer)`.

Any literal integer in Haskell is rewritten by Haskell by wrapping it in a `fromInteger` call. So:

```
(2 :: Sum Integer) == ((fromInteger (2 :: Integer)) :: Sum Integer)
```

Haskell just allows the notation on the left hand side so it's easier to type, but it's equivalent to the code on the right.

The `fromInteger` function has the following type signature:

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
```

So `(fromInteger (2 :: Integer))` has type `Num a => a`

Somewhere in the libraries you'll have an instance like the following:

```
instance Num a => Num (Sum a) where ...
```

As `Integer` is a `Num`, so is `Sum Integer`.

So we can convert `Num a => a` to `Sum Integer` just by substituting `a = Sum Integer`.

Finally, we have the `Semigroup` function:

(<>) :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a

There's also an instance:

```
instance Num a => Semigroup (Sum a) where ...
```

Somewhere in the semigroups modules, and as the `(<>)` function specifies that the left and right argument and result has to be the same argument, then if we know one of these we know the other two. We know that the right argument is `Sum Integer`, so we have to check we can convert the left argument to `Sum Integer`.

Remember from before, `1` really means `fromInteger (1 :: Integer)`. We've mention before that there's a `fromInteger` implementation to `Sum Integer`, so this is fine. We can then use the semigroup operation `(<>)` on them as they're now the same type which is also a `Semigroup`.

**Answer for update**

`Num` is not a type, it's a class. `Integer` is a type, but as I've said before, `43` is not an `Integer`, it's `fromInteger 43`. It can be an `Integer` or it can be any `Num` type. Some of those `Num` types may be a `Monoid`.

Try `x = mappend (43 :: Integer)` and you'll find the code now fails to compile because you're forcing `Num` to be an `Int` which doesn't have a `Monoid` instance.

However, `x = mappend (43 :: Sum Integer)` does have a `Monoid` instance so should compile fine.